# 文の組み立て JLPT N1 Question about word order

Tags: grammar, jlpt, word-order

I am currently practicing for the N1 JLPT, where the questions require us to assemble the sentences in the correct order. Although the book provides the correct answer, it doesn't provide the correct order of the phrases. Hence, I would like to check whether the following sentences are in the correct order as I have trouble figuring out the correct sequence.

> 1. わたしたちは、「きれいな」「量が」「かつ」「十分で」水を必要としている。
>      (「かつ」 is the correct answer provided, and not sure about the other 3 positions)
> 2. 節約生活も、子供の教育のため「だから」「こそ」「我慢できる」「の」かもしれない。
>      (「こそ」 is the correct phrase, but I'm not sure of the reasoning as to why the 「の」 is in the 4th space.

Thank you for the help! :D

Comment: Link [here](http://wordgrammar.net/japanese-language-proficiency-test-jlpt-n1-grammar-exercise-12/)

Comment: So, what do you think the translations ought to be? What would きれいな量 mean?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/29220/what-is-the-meaning-of-%e3%81%aa%e3%81%ae-here/29222#29222

Comment: Likely answer to [question 2](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/56095/use-of-%E3%81%AE-with-%E3%81%8B%E3%82%82%E3%81%97%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)

Comment: @Yamacure Thank you for the clarification! Can I confirm whether かつ in this context means "and"?

Comment: @BJCUAI Thank you for the links for explanation!

Comment: @Yamacure, Please try to avoid answering questions in the comments section.

Comment: @InvadersMustDie, Please ask one question per post. You can edit out one of the questions and post it separately. Also please try to give each question a specific title to help future users find them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> わたしたちは、量が十分でかつきれいな水を必要としている。
>     We need water that is both sufficient in quantity and clean.

十分で水 is ungrammatical for obvious reasons. I believe you already know [how to join two na-adjectives](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/50368/5010) using で, so please learn [how to use かつ](https://www.nihongomaster.com/dictionary/entry/19729/katsu) to emphasize the meaning of "and". You can rephrase this as きれい**で**かつ量が十分**な**水. See how で and な have been swapped. In case you have trouble parsing 量が十分な水, [this discussion](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/53581/5010) may help.

> 節約生活も、子供の教育のためだからこそ我慢できるのかもしれない。

This one is already correct.